# react-mentions onChange trigger twice when copy paste

Tags: reactjs

https://github.com/signavio/react-mentions i'm using it.

it is working but MentionsInput onChange triggered twice when copy paste. then my textarea doubled content

```
      <MentionsInput
        autoFocus={autoFocus}
        value={text}
        placeholder="Write comment..."
        className="mentions"
        allowSuggestionsAboveCursor
        onChange={(e, value, plainText, mens) => {
          setText(value)
          setMentions(mens.map(m => m.id))
        }}
      >
        <Mention
          trigger="@"
          data={loadMentionOptions}
          markup="[@__display__](/profile/__id__)"
          displayTransform={(id, display) => `@${display}`}
          renderSuggestion={renderMentionOptions}
          appendSpaceOnAdd
        />
      </MentionsInput>
```